# PHP Crawler for submit a from on an external site and get result

Tags: php, html, forms, web-crawler

For a system I am developing I need to programmatically go to a specific page. Fill out one field in the form (I know the id and name of the input element), submit it and store the results.

I do have the permission to do this from the site i am getting the information from as well.

The problem i have is, i believe the script works, but because the 'action' of the external form is redirecting to the same page, and displaying the result in a table, it just tries to redirect my personal webpage to the same directory, which doesn't exist on my server of course.

Any help is appreciated, heres what i have so far:

```
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables

//URL IS SET, I HAVE JUST TOOK IT OUT OF THIS CODE SNIPPET
$urltopost = 'blahblah.com';

$datatopost = array ( 
's_3_2_5_0' => 0130016825566667, 'SWEFo' => 'SWEForm3_0',  'SWEField' => 's_3_1_0_0', 'SWENeedContext' => 'true',
'W' => 't', 'SWECmd' => 'InvokeMethod', 'SWEMethod' => 'SearchForLicence', 'SWESP' => 'false', 'SWEDIC' => 'false',
'SWEReqRowId' => '0','SWEView' => 'LDL+Licence+Query+View','SWEC' => '3','SWEBID' => '1363349905','SWEGHOTO' => 'true',
'SWETS' => '1363349913267', 'SWEApplet' => 'LDL+Query+Licences');

$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $returndata;
```

Comment: Wow!, looks cool like a `Crawler / Spammer` or whatever.. I believe you need to change the `$urltopost` to where form send its `REQUEST` not to the form. and take all fields from `form` and sent it to `action=www.example.com`

Comment: @Rafee sounds like a good idea but the forms redirects to the same page

Comment: What is the `extract($_POST)` good for?

Comment: try with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0) > CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true, this option follows the redirect, might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form returns HTML with JavaScript that does the redirect.

```
window.location.replace("/web/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=LDL+Asset+Query‌​+Results+View&SWERF=1");
```

You need to remove that from $returndata before outputing it. Anyway there are many other relative URLs in the HTML, like URLs of images.

You should better extract just data from the result and produce your own HTML page (search SO for "Extract Data from HTML using PHP").

Comment: The $returndata should be what the form returns, is there any way around a JS redirect?

Comment: The form returns some HTML probably. Can you show it to us? Probably no point finding workaround for possible JS, before we actually know if there's any JS at all.

Comment: https://portal.the-sia.org.uk/web/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&amp;SWEView=LDL+Licence+Query+View - this is the form

Comment: 1) I do not know what too fill in, so I cannot get to the results. 2) The form submits to `/web/start.swe`. You do not have this anywhere in your code.

Comment: Just the first field, with the license number is what i am wanting to input.. try entering this: 0130016825566667

Comment: There's indeed `window.location.replace("/web/start.swe?SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=LDL+Asset+Query+Results+View&SWERF=1");`. Check yourself. You need to remove that from `$returndata` before outputing it. Anyway there are many other relative URLs in the HTML, like URLs of  images. You should better extract just data from the result and produce your own HTML page (search SO for "Extract Data from HTML using PHP"). Also please do not forget to accept the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: I have tested it by disabling javascipt, and it produces some markup for the form, just not the results from the form submit